# Add values in .css file dynamically

Tags: css

I want to know is it possible to add values for classes created in .css file to a tag dynamically?

Now, if I have `<div class="textFrame">` in .html file and in css file I have declaration as-

```
.textFrame
{ 
     overflow:hidden; 
     position:absolute;
}
```

Now, I want to add style attribute for `<div>` with left, top, height and width etc attributes. My question is, is it possible to create some variables let us say, left, top, height or width in .textFrame class(in .css file) and assign values dynamically to these variables for each `<div>` tag. Actually there are no of textFrames(`<div>` tags) with different values of top, left, height and width.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Are you trying to style elements based on their existing styles?

Comment: @gdoron - thnx for your quick reply, but actually i am not aware of ajax. Can you please provide me sample code.

Comment: @blender - actually i am creating a html file. while creating it i am reading values for those style variables from my another document(i have a tool that is providing me all those values) but now when i am creating html file, i just want to simplify the writing task in html file with declaring variables in .css file

Answer (score 2):

With use of jquery you are able to add classes dynamically in tags

eg:

```
<div class="textFrame">
    .......
    .......
</div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.textFrame').css('height','500px');
}
```

For multiple div has same class
eg:

`<div class="textFrame" id="1"> ....... ....... </div>`
`<div class="textFrame" id="2"> ....... ....... </div>`

Jquery :

`$(document).ready(function() {`
`$('.textFrame').each(function(e){`
`if($('.textFrame').attr('id') == '1'){`
`$('.textFrame').css('height','500px');`
`} else if($('.textFrame').attr('id') == '2'){`
`$('.textFrame').css('height','300px');`
`}`
`});`

Comment: If I have five <div class="textFrame"> tags and the height for each <div> is different. How can I set height for each div?

Comment: <div class="textFrame" id="1">
    .......
    .......
</div>
<div class="textFrame" id="2">
    .......
    .......
</div>


.each(function(e){
   if($('.textFrame').attr('id') == '1'){
  $('.textFrame').css('height','500px');
 } else if($('.textFrame').attr('id') == '1'){
  $('.textFrame').css('height','300px');
 }
});

Answer (score 1):

If they all have different attributes, it makes no sense to dynamically change the source stylesheet. You should probably use Javascript to change each element's style dynamically. jQuery makes that very easy.